# Program that asks for amount and displays amount in units of dollars, quarters, dimes, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, Here is what I have so far:

```
def enter():
    amount=float(input('Enter cost:'))
    remainder=amount*100
    dollars(remainder)
    quarters(remainder)
    dimes(remainder)
    nickels(remainder)
    cents(remainder)
def dollars(remainder):
    dollars=remainder//100
    print('Dollars:', dollars)
def quarters(remainder):
    quarters=remainder//25
    print('Quarters:',quarters)
def dimes(remainder):
    dimes=remainder//10
    print('Dimes:', dimes)
def nickels(remainder):
    nickels=remainder//5
    print('Nickels:', nickels)
def cents(remainder):
    cents=remainder//1
    print('Cents:', cents)
enter()
```

The problem is that when an amount is entered, for example, 5.25, it displays:
5.0 dollars,
21.0 quarters

I need it to display:
5.0 dollars,
1.0 quarters

Comment: Hint: You need to perform subtraction...

Comment: (To elaborate, think why did you call the variable `remainder`.)

Comment: So I would need to subtract the previous units for each function?

Comment: Well you have 5.0 dollars (same as 5*4=20 quarters) and 21 quarters. To get your desired value you have to make sure the units are the same (make sure you're comparing quarters to quarters) and then subtract. So the 21 quarters - 20 quarters = your desired 1 quarter.

Comment: ok, I see what you're saying. But this program has to work for any amount of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just do this:

```
def enter():
    amount=float(input('Enter cost:'))
    remainder=amount*100
    dollar=dollars(remainder)
    remainder-=dollar
    print('Dollars:', dollar)
    quarter=quarters(remainder)
    ......

def dollars(remainder):
    dollars=remainder//100
    return dollars
.....
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to work with it a little but it helped a lot.